# Traffic jam problem. How to avoid it?

Tags: cities-skylines

During my first few attempts with skylines I tried to use techniques I read about to control traffic flow like large one way roads, then roads beside
    the highway that are used as puffer zone, round goings for heavy traffic areas, ....
    but run into troubles there and not sure what I'm doing wrong. First the streets take up WAY more place than I had thought possible and second as in the screenshots below.......there are some perma traffic jam areas (the south has which is cut out has another one way that goes from right to left).

The elevated roads and the elevated circle are all highways.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nK9uAGo.png]

Comment: One of your problems might be that at the exit area (the one you have stuck an arrow on) of the roundabout where the traffic is, its a sharp turn rather than a gradual bend. Try remaking that road so that cars have to slow down less before getting off.

Comment: You might also want to try having the exit before the entrance, so that traffic coming into your city isn't getting in the way of traffic leaving.

Comment: I've also just noticed that the road above your permajam is broken - it's one way, but one section of the road (highlighted by a T shape made of black and red) is one way in the other direction, making the entire road unusable.

Comment: Looking at the arrows on your image -- looks like you have it set to drive on the right, but that the round-about is clockwise (i.e. a left turn to enter)? If I'm seeing that right (and I might not be), then I recommend making the circle right-turn-to-enter. (But the broken road that Dr R Dizzle mentioned is probably the bigger issue!)

Comment: tnx overlooked the broken road! although it is mostly to southwest and southeast that the jammed cars try to go to. And if I get you right: The way that roundtrips should go is in the opposite hand of the trffic (thus counter clock for right and clockwise for left handed traffic)?

Comment: @Thomas If your traffic is driving on the left, you want your roundabout to go clockwise. This means that traffic can exit the roundabout while traffic in the same lane can enter it, as they don't need to crossover each other - take a look at how real life roundabouts work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several things you can do to help this traffic problem, the main ones being;

1. Make sure that the traffic leaving your city can exit the roundabout before traffic entering the city comes on. This will mean that the roundabout is not dealing with both incoming and outgoing traffic at the same time.
2. Make it so that the traffic leaving the roundabout doesn't have such a sharp corner to take. Cars have to slow down for sharper turns, so by making it a more gradual turn rather than a corner (the Exit Ramp road type might help), traffic can move off the roundabout quicker and easier.
3. The road above your permatraffic is broken, with one section of it being "one way" in the wrong direction to the rest of it. Fixing this will allow traffic to utilise this road, which may help.

Answer (score 3):

The advise by Dr R Dizzle regarding optimizing that roundabout sounds good. But in addition to following these suggestions you should also try to reduce traffic overall.

- Make sure you have a good public transportation system with subways connecting all your districts and then bus lines transporting the people from the subway stations to the surrounding.
- Balance your industries so that you fulfill most needs yourself. This reduces traffic from import and export (specialized industries supply non-specialized industries and non-specialized industries supply commercial buildings). You can use the "Outside Connection" overview to check which buildings export or import.
- When you still need to import and export, make sure most of it leaves or enters your city by freight train or harbor.